# Prevent enabling of shift bypass - Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to prevent database users from being able to view the linked tables in the navigation pane of an Access 2010 database. I have hidden the pane and disabled the F11 key.

I am aware that you can disable the functionality of the SHIFT key that permits you to bypass the access start-up options as per [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/826765/how-to-enforce-or-disable-the-startup-options-in-an-access-database-pr).

My question is whether it is possible to prevent a user from re-enabling the shift key either from within the database itself or remotely via another database. If this is not possible does anyone know of the next best method I can use to prevent users viewing the tables in the navigation pane (I know access isn't the most secure database but it's all we have in the office atm)

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried converting to accde but was still able to re-enable the bypass :(

Comment: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=51479

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks for the reply. That article appears to show how to disable the shift bypass key (via the same method in the article I mentioned in the question). I am hoping to find out if there is a way to prevent users from using the same method to enable it again.

Comment: Access is a desktop database. If you need client/server, use client/server.

Comment: Hi Mat. Access is the only option I have atm. I know it's not ideal but I thought it was worth checking if there is a way to prevent users from viewing the tables

Comment: Make them use another client, e.g. Excel? FWIW SQL Server Express is a free download, and with it you can easily migrate your data from Access to an actual database server.

Comment: Excel may be an option. IT won't allow me to download any files onto the company computers. So are we saying that doing this purely in Access is definitely a dead end?

Comment: I haven't used Access in a decade, and when I did I didn't bother with "security" because users were all in my department. I don't know if it's a dead-end, but if IT knows you need data and they can't be bothered to supply you with a real RDBMS solution, then they can't blame users breaking the Access database.

Comment: There's no such thing as true security in Access. You could even just pull out all database objects with a second database if you got shift bypass to work, essentially bypassing your security. The best I have come up with is the following: encrypt your main database, and use a second database to store encrypted versions of the encryption key per user that they can decrypt using their password (I've developed a small GUI they can use to enter their name and pass, and it decrypts the main DB if correct). That way, no-one (except me) has the main encryption key, and it's kind of secure.

Comment: Of course using SQL server for the back end will not change this issue. (so suggestings to use SQL server will NOT fix this issue). If users can grab + see the data from SQL server, then in Excel, or via linked tables in Access would  not change this security issue. What you can do however is in your startup code check if shift by-pass has been enabled and then disable it, and then exit the database. (it requires a re-start to take effect). So even if users disabled the shift key, your startup would re-enable. And using a compiled (accde) will prevent users modifying any code.

Comment: I prefer using the ms-access runtime, it protects code and objects and it's for free. Of course the .accde can be copied and opened with the full version, but if you use a SQL-Server there is no data on that machine.

Comment: The most secured option I can think of is a terminal server that runs ms access. No access to the frontend-file for the users, but of course you have to prevent exports. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to security in Access is the following:

Encrypt the main database using a complex password.

Use a second database to log in to this encrypted database. The second database stores usernames, user salts, and an encrypted version of the main database password with the user password. This way, no user needs to have the main password.

Then, compile the second database, so it's harder to modify the database and print the main encryption key.

Weaknesses:

1. Revoking access to a certain user only works if he doesn't have a
   backup of the login database (or you have to change the encryption key on
   the main database, forcing you to recreate accounts for every user).
2. The encryption I'm using is RC4 (implementation in VB by wqw found as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025644/vb6-encrypt-text-using-password)), which isn't that strong
3. A tech savvy user that has a valid password could decompile the database and use it to acquire the main database password
4. If you're not signing your databases and enforcing all databases to be signed, someone might modify or replace it to weaken security

To go through all the details is too much, so [here](https://evona.nl/misc_uploads/logindb.accdb) is my implementation.

File metadata: size: 672 KB, SHA1 hash: `19A6C756B8D5B0CDCEBE505B289062A1BBD94DEC`

Quick manual: on first run it prompts main database password, location, first user name and password. After that, you can just use the forms to do anything you want.

Note that it's earlier work, and I haven't deeply thought about SQL injection (I use doublequote escaping and am ashamed for it). However, this isn't a security risk for the main database, it only opens up a possibility for a destructive hack (and someone with write access to the database file can probably destroy it anyway).

It's not compiled and menus aren't hidden, so you can easily inspect and modify it. When implementing it, hide all menus and compile it.

The database, as all SO content, is licensed CC BY SA 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Of course using SQL server for the back end will not change this issue. (so suggesting's to use SQL server will NOT fix this issue). If users can grab + see the data from SQL server, then in Excel, or via linked tables in Access would not change this security issue. What you can do however is in your Access startup code check if shift by-pass has been enabled and then disable it, and then exit the database. (it requires a re-start to take effect). So even if users disabled the shift key, your startup would re-enable. And using a compiled (accde) will prevent users modifying any code.

So simply check the status of the shift key on application startup, and if its been enabled, simply use your referenced code to disable the shift key and exit.

To be fair, the above is not 100% solid, since in theory your startup code would not run if the shift key was enabled. Another tip would be to always provide users with a shortcut to use (and that shortcut would include the /runtime switch which also disables shift key regardless of setting - so this would give "somewhat" an extra layer here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately I cannot use this idea in my scenario. As you have mentioned, it is no use adding a condition in the start up code when that code can be bypassed anyway. I will continue trying to find another solution. Thanks anyway