# Launch password protected database and close existing one

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to set up a "Launcher" database which contains VBA code that will open a second database which is password protected. I can then convert the launcher db to accde so the VBA containing the password cannot be read.

I have the following code so far.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim acc As Access.Application
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim strDbName As String

 strDbName = "C:\database Folder\secureDB.accdb"
 Set acc = New Access.Application
 acc.Visible = True
 Set db = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDbName, False, False, ";PWD=swordfish")

 acc.OpenCurrentDatabase (strDbName)
 
 Application.Quit
  
End Sub
```

When the launcher db is opened a form loads which subsequently fires the above code. It works but the problem is the last line which is intended to close the launcher db only but closes both databases. I have also tried opening the main database using Shell but am unable to pass the password this way.

How can I close the first database while keeping the second open?

Comment: I would suggest open with command-line options in a shell script or search for "access frontend updater" to see how they do this ( I think one is called mdbloader).

Comment: Or try `acc.Application.Quit'.

Comment: Note that access databases can be decompiled, so the string can be read (through some effort). As said in my previous comment, I have a database lying around that stores an encrypted db password with a user password, so only users that have a valid password can log in.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: And the password is stored under the keyboard;-). Maybe better to check windows login to see if user can login?

Comment: @BitAccesser that's pseudosecurity. You have to assume a hacker can read all unencrypted parts of your database. You can modify my implementation (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179795/prevent-enabling-of-shift-bypass-access-2010)) to check that also and use the Windows username by default, but that doesn't really strengthen it. Of course, proper password management is everything, but the Windows password might be taped under the keyboard also.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Pwd's are just as save as the users care about, but many don't care and your whole protection measures are undermined. I thought there are secure ways to get windows auth by active directory (Ènviron("username")`is not). and authentice with a token or biometrics additionally. What do you think about a terminal server? Wouldn't that be the best option?

Comment: @BitAccesser The entire problem is that users can edit your database. Users can open a database using the shift click or by disabling VBA, open the navigation pane, and mess around with it. Users can use VBA from a second database to export tables without opening your database or running any code in it. You can't work around this (short of some sort of remoteapp service where users actually aren't able to create files or move the database). The only two real modes of security are denying access to the file, and encryption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154372/discussion-between-bitaccesser-and-erik-von-asmuth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim acc As Access.Application
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim strDbName As String

 strDbName = "C:\database Folder\secureDB.accdb"
 Set acc = New Access.Application
 acc.Visible = True
 acc.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbName, False, "swordfish"
 Set db = acc.CurrentDb() 'Don't know why you want a reference to the db
 acc.UserControl = True
 Application.Quit
End Sub
```

The relevant part is `acc.UserControl = True`, that forces the DB to stay visible and stops it from closing as soon as the reference to the Application object gets destroyed.

A sample database that stores the main database password encrypted with a salted user password can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196870)

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't heard of the UserControl method before. I had been stuck on this for ages. I am trying to avoid having to provide every user with a password which is why I couldn't go with your other method. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Incidentally, if you would like to add this as an answer to my first question, I'd be happy to accept that also. If not, I'll just add it myself so the question isn't left open. Just thought you deserved the credit

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting the accepted answer to work properly. I was able to make work with:

```
Public Function OpenAccessDb(strVerPath, strFileName, sRecordset, strPwd)
    'You may also need to have the following References Added:
    'Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library & Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object
    'Visual Basic for Applications// Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library// OLE Automation//
    'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library// Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library// Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
    Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine, oDB As DAO.Database, oRS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sPath As String
    'sPath = GetProperDirectory(strVerPath, strFileName) ' you can bypass this function by setting the path manually below and commenting this out.
    sPath = "C:\database Folder\secureDB.accdb"'manually set the path here and comment out line above
    Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
    Set oDB = oDAO.OpenDatabase(sPath, False, True, "MS Access;PWD=" & strPwd)
    Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset(sRecordset)

    ''paste to call this function
    ''note this function utilizes the GetProperDirectory function.
    ''The GetProperDirectory function uses xxxxx as the location source
    ''therefore the strVerPath should start after \xxxxx\yyyyyy\yyyyy\DB.accdb
    'strVerPath = "\yyyyyy\yyyyy\"
    'strFileName= "DB.accdb"
    'sRecordSet= "table in access DB" 'the table you are sending the data to
    'strPwd = "password' 'this is the password that allows access to the database
    'booOpenSend= OpenAccessDb(strVerPath, strFileName, sRecordSet, strPwd)
    ''end paste
End Function
```