# MS Access decrypt .accdb file with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Ciao,
I'd need to decrypt an .accdb file from an other .accdb file (on a form where I ask the user for password for the decryption).
Is it possible? How can I do it?
Thank you
g

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193339/access-vba-launch-password-protected-database-and-close-existing-one

Comment: the referenced topic does not offer solution for the remote decryption which would be my goal here.