# Protect Access's Startup Bypass

Tags: ms-access, password-protection, ms-access-2016, data-integrity

Looking to protect data in linked tables from being edited directly.

I've tired googling this, or looking on this site. I've found a lot of variations but I can not find an answer I am looking for.

Using Access 2016. It's split into back-end for data tables and the linked front-end for users. I have an issue with users Shift-Entering the front-end and bypassing the forms. From there they directly open the linked tables they want, and edit the data directly. I would like some form of enforcement to prevent this, but still allow myself access to do so when needed.
Ideally this will not prompt users for a password when they open the Front-End normally.

Comment: Did you Google this? I found: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826765/how-to-enforce-or-disable-the-startup-options-in-an-access-database-pr  which explains how to prevent using the Shift key to bypass startup options.

Comment: and without a login system, how would access know if it's you or someone else?

Comment: Half the answer, this disables everything whole-sale. Which is good for preventing users from getting in, but also prevents any sort of access myself. VBA does allow flexibility ...

Comment: It doesn't *prevent* you from your desired access... all you need to do is have code that *only you* can run to turn off all of the security settings. Hope you only distribute an MDE front-end to protect forms, code,etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent enabling of shift bypass - Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179795/prevent-enabling-of-shift-bypass-access-2010)

Comment: At work there's only a couple of us who have the full version of Access.  Everyone else has the free runtime version which severely limits what the average use can do.

Comment: Might want to look into Gary Robinson's book if it's still available. [Microsoft Access Database Protection and Security.] Pretty great.

Comment: Found a solution with Wayne G's answer. Creating a secondary file that allowed me to control the Shift-Open option of another database as well as some other demi-permissions I have created. (I don't think I can mark my post as solved until someone else replies?)