# Prevent users from being able to bypass a login form on MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a login form with a combo box for the user type (Admin, User) and a text box for the password. The code for the form is as follows.

```
Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()

If IsNull(Me.cboUser) Then
    MsgBox "You need to select a user!", vbCritical
    Me.cboUser.SetFocus
Else
    If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) Then
        If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
            MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
            Me.txtPassword = Null
            Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        End If
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FE1"
        Me.Visible = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
        Me.txtPassword = Null
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboUser_AfterUpdate()
Forms!frmLogin!cboUser.Column (2)
End Sub
```

It's technically working (users can login with their user type and password), but they're also able to just close out of it and access the rest of the database.

How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: Disable the X close button. Disable right click shortcut menu. Hide the navigation pane.

Answer (score 2):

You can both enable the `Modal` property, and disable the `CloseButton` property:

[image]

Note that, when using the `Modal` property, you will need to close the form when you're done: `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` instead of `Me.Visible = False`
However, this is still away from proper security.

It gets a tiny bit more secure if you deny closing the form using VBA:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
     Cancel = True
     If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) And Not Me.cboUser.Column(3)  Then
        Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub
```

A cautionary warning about denying closing through VBA: this will also trigger when closing the database, denying people from closing the database if they haven't entered the right password! Any person opening it without a valid password will either have to terminate Access through the task manager, be tech-savvy enough to bypass this (I mentioned it was unsecure, right?), or terminate it by doing a forced shutdown of their computer.

However, for something close to true user-based security, you will have to change your design altogether. I've provided my considerations and a sample for a more proper design in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196870/7296893)