# Is the .accdb password of an Access Database readable from its .accde file?

Tags: database, ms-access, security, office365, ms-office

I am currently developing an Access-Database for my company. In order to prevent Users from unauthorized changing of the VBA-code I have encrypted my Back- and Frontend .accdb file. I continued by compiling my frontend to an .accde file, which is not currently not password-protected.

Is it possible to read the used password for Front- and Backend using **the .accde file only**?

Answer (score 0):

The .accde isn't connected to the .accdb it was created from, so if the .accde isn't encrypted, I don't see how it would contain the .accdb password.

But the backend password is most probably readable, by opening the .accde from another database and browsing the tabledefs and their properties (connection string).

To prevent this, you must encrypt the .accde too, and launch it from a seperate application, so you don't have to provide the password to the users.

Here is an approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196870/3820271